# Does static provide additional guaranties in JMM context?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility, java-memory-model

I am reading about java singleton and I've met strange things.

I will refer to [following artice](http://www.journaldev.com/171/thread-safety-in-java-singleton-classes-with-example-code) as example(you can easy find more)

Author provides the following singleton:

```
public class ASingleton {

    private static ASingleton instance = new ASingleton();

    private ASingleton() {
    }

    public static ASingleton getInstance() {            
        return instance;
    }

}
```

and comments:

> **Pros:**
>    -*Thread safety without synchronization*
>    - Easy to implement
>
> **Cons:**
>    - Early creation of resource that might not be used in the application.
>    -The client application can’t pass any argument, so we can’t reuse it.
>        For example, having a generic singleton class for database connection
>      where client application supplies database server properties.

I want to get clarification about **Thread safety without synchronization** point.

I've read concurrency in practice book and don't remember anything related with this.

I missed something or this clarification is not relevant?

Additionally I want to tell you that you can encounter the same singleton but field marked as `static final` instead of just `static`
**P.S.**

I understand that I can read [JMM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)  and this one contains the answer but I am usual guy and I can't undertand this source.

Comment: You don't have the guarantees of visibility (which would confer the thread safety) because the field isn't `final`.

Comment: @Andy, yes, I've corrected it a bit because text unrelated with code. I think author descibed the variant I provided

Comment: it would have to be `static final` in order to get the properties described.

Comment: Note!  When the author says "thread safety", that does _not_ mean that it makes the entire singleton thread safe.  It only means that the `getInstance()` method is thread safe.  A thread that calls `getInstance()` will never see the singleton object in a partially initialized or uninitialized state.

Comment: @ james large Why? getInstance is not synchronized

Answer (score 1):

According to [securecoding.cert.org](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) this is a valid pattern:

> Variables that are declared static and initialized at declaration or from a static initializer are guaranteed to be fully constructed before being made visible to other threads. However, this solution forgoes the benefits of lazy initialization.

The point is: *loading* classes is a well defined operation. And executing static initializing code falls into the same category.

It is important to understand: JMM knowledge is only "required" when you go for the `static field` + **lazy** init variant:

> Initialization of the static helper field is deferred until the getInstance() method is called. The necessary happens-before relationships are created by the combination of the class loader's actions loading and initializing the Holder instance and the guarantees provided by the Java memory model (JMM). This idiom is a better choice than the double-checked locking idiom for lazily initializing static fields [Bloch 2008]. However, this idiom cannot be used to lazily initialize instance fields [Bloch 2001].

`Final`ly: the `final` keyword should **not** affect this at all. Using `final` is much more about *expressing* your intent to declare a well, *final* thing - instead of one that gets potentially updated later on.

Comment: class loading != class initialization  from my point of view. All statuc fields and satic blocks initialize when access happens. P.S. maybe it depends on classloader flags but by default it works so

Comment: this text related with example where field declared as **static final**

Comment: *"All statuc fields and static blocks initialize when access happens."* - Basically, yes ... but it is more complicated than just "access".

Answer (score 1):

That idiom is sound  with respect to the JMM.

There is a *happens before* relationship between the static initialization of a class and the use of any static variables.  This is a consequence of the locking that occurs during the *initailization procedure* described in [JLS 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

---

According to my reading, `instance` does not need to be declared as `final` here to get the required *happens-before*.  It is advisable for other reasons though.

Comment: can you discover other reasons?

Comment: I don't see quote in JLS which prove your answer

Comment: "For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock LC".  Step 1: "Synchronize on the inititialization lock".  Etcetera.  Look at the fine print that talks about how the procedure can be optimized **provided** that happens-before is preserved.  Finally go to the JMM section and note that 1) acquiring a lock is a synchronization action, and 2) synchronizes-with implies happens-before.

Comment: Like I said, this is a *consequence* of the procedure.  The JLS authors assume that 12.4.2 will be read / interpreted in the context of other relevant parts of the spec.  (They often don't spell things out ... if they can be logically inferred from other parts of the spec.  Redundancy leads to errors.)